# Where is an Android project name held?

Tags: android, eclipse, refactoring, project, rename

I renamed my Android project and although it all appears OK in Eclipse, when I install it onto any devices (even new devices on which it has never previously been installed), it shows with the old name.

I've looked through the Manifest file and again, it all seems to be OK (with the new name), I can't work out where the installed version is getting it's name from.  Where is it stored?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the name under your icon is stored in `app_name` in `res/values/strings.xml`. Changing its value there will change the name.

Renaming the project only renames it in Eclipse's workspace, and does not actually change the name.

Answer (score 1):

Android gets the name from  the manifest file which usually references the string resource described in @Raghav Sood's answer i.e:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
```